# Use custom post type for a store locator

Tags: php, plugin-development

I want to make a store locator. I've registered a cpt named portfolio and I want to add to it all the needed info like latitude and longitude that will be used to display a marker on a leaflet.js map. 
I'm not sure how to proceed. I need to open a popup on the backend that will let the user search and then select a location on the map and after this, save all the post information like title, post content and the latitude/longitude of the place to add to the store locator that is displayed on the fornt-end.
Can I use the `wp_insert_post` function to achieve this or it's better to use the standard ui of wordpress? If I use the standard ui, I'don't know how to open a popup only for this kind of posts, will `edit_form_after_editor` do the trick? How the custom post meta (lat/lng) can be added?

Comment: Find a way to extract coordinates from a map, this is a front end matter. Then add a custom meta field to this specific post type which implements your map selector, then save your custom meta fields info by hooking to `save_post` action.

Comment: On the fromt-end there will be only the map with the locations added from the back-end so all the work will be demanded to the back-end. I'm not sure about the `save_post` this because I want to use the standard save or update button of the UI, I want only set the meta fields programmatically

Comment: That's what the `save_post` hook is used for. You retrieve your meta field values from `$_POST` and set them with the `add_post_meta` function.

Comment: You may look into custom library called CMB2 https://github.com/CMB2/CMB2/wiki/Basic-Usage#getting-started using it you can add custom fields to portfolio CPT and using custom field called map you can allow user to click on anywhere on the map in dashboard and it will store that info as coordinates, for other info like name and address you may add more fields next to map field using CMB2 library. Here is link to map field type https://github.com/mustardBees/cmb_field_map/blob/master/readme.md see if it helps in your situation.

Comment: @Himad thank you for the clarification